# Fill in N lags based on a variable in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, lag

I have two columns in my data frame, value and num_leads. I'd like to create a third column that stores the value's value from n rows below - where n is whatever number is stored in num_leads. Here's an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(value = c(1:5),
                  num_leads = c(2, 3, 1, 1, 0))
```

Desired output:

```
  value num_leads  result
1     1         2       3
2     2         3       5
3     3         1       4
4     4         1       5
5     5         0       5
```

I have tried using the lead function in dplyr but unfortunately it seems all the leads must have the same number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using indexing

```
with(df1, value[seq_along(value) + num_leads])
```

where `seq_along(value)` gives the row number, and by adding to `num_leads` you can pull out the right value

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
 df1$result <- df1$value[df1$value + df1$num_leads]
```

Comment: This would not work if `value` would not be equal to the row number. Well, by chance maybe.